Problem of increasing topic jitter when all nodes are started
Good day all,
System details:
RaspberryPi 5
Ubuntu 24.04
ROS JAZZY
I have an IMU driver publishing my IMU data to a ros topic. Running this driver together with another driver for a stereo-camera pair, works fine. I am able to publish the imu data topic at up to about 450Hz. However, I set it to 250Hz as this is enough for the application.
When I run the above two drivers with the rest of my system's nodes (FYI: OpenVINS), the jitter of the topic increases greatly. See the plot I have added (initial spike is when all nodes are launched). I have also added a plot of the frequency. The ros bag recording was started and a few seconds later the rest of the nodes where launched.
Does anyone have ideas or suggestions for things I can check so that I can ultimately go about fixing this jitter issue and keep the imu topic at a constant 250Hz?
Further info:

The Hz of the camera topics only reduces slightly when all the nodes are launched.
I checked my CPU loads, all 4 CPUs of the RaspberryPI are running at around 82%.

Plots:



You are expecting too much from a non-realtime operating system like linux, especially if you have a lot of processes executing. In my experience an 82% load on all CPUs is a very heavy load.

Thanks @Mike973

Did further testing now, running without RViz, so CPU load is considerably less. The topic jitter is much better and the imu topic is able to remain at 250Hz. So, marking your answer as correct @Mike973
